# XSD schema for XML with same element name but different attribute values

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I never worked on XSD before. Today I need to validate 10 millions XMLS in database. After going through different techniques to do the validation I decided to go with XSD and xml methods in c# to validate the xmls. i need help to create XSD for my xml structure. The playfield is repeated arbitrary times in different xmls.

```
<PlayAttributes>
  <PlayFields>
    <PlayField ID="XInfo.XInfo_QBAtPass" TS="">P</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="XInfo.XInfo_Huddle" TS="">F</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="XInfo.XInfo_DefScoreAfter" TS="">30</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="Play.Offense.Off_Text_21" TS="2013-11-15 13:55:54">MWMUG</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="Play.Shared.playResult" TS="2013-10-21 07:46:57">0</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="Play.Migration.repTime" TS="2013-10-21 07:46:57">123</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="Play.Migration.offensiveTeam" TS="2013-10-21 07:46:57">CAR</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="Play.Offense.Off_Front" TS="2013-11-15 13:55:50">N42ELX</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="XInfo.XInfo_LateralSeq" TS="">F</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="Play.Offense.Off_Slot_Route" TS="2013-11-15 13:09:41">TREY</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="Play.Offense.Off_Text_24" TS="2013-11-15 13:09:37">G FR</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="XInfo.XInfo_EventCode" TS="">Incomplete Pass</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="XInfo.XInfo_PlayersRushed" TS="">4</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="XInfo.XInfo_YdGained" TS="">0</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="XInfo.XInfo_Receiver" TS="">Quick, Brian (390159)</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="XInfo.XInfo_Location" TS="">L</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="Play.Shared.Field_2_Minute" TS="2013-11-15 13:08:07">2</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="XInfo.XInfo_DriveStart" TS="">692</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="Football.FrontTypeNew" TS="2013-11-15 13:55:48">E</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="XInfo.XInfo_OffRole1" TS="">NO-No Data</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="XInfo.XInfo_OffRole2" TS="">NO-No Data</PlayField>
    <PlayField ID="XInfo.XInfo_Unit" TS="">Offense</PlayField>
  </PlayFields>
</PlayAttributes>
```

Comment: Please read [**Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/290085)

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth looking at the [XML Schema Definition Tool (xsd)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe), particularly the section on [example usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe#examples):

> The following command generates an XML schema from `myFile.xml` and
>   saves it to the specified directory.
>
> ```
> xsd myFile.xml /outputdir:myOutputDir
> ```

Comment: thnaks i found this one helpful too https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18426/XSD-Tutorial-Part-of-Elements-and-Attributes